# Reducing the Average Number of Comparisons in Selection

Tags: algorithm

The problem here is to reduce the average number of comparisons need in a selection sort.

I am reading an article on this and here is text snippet:

> More generally, a sample **S'** of **s** elements is chosen from the **n**
>   elements. Let "**delta**" be some number, which we will choose later so
>   as to minimize the average number of comparisons used by the
>   procedure. We find the  (**v1** = (**k** * **s**)/(**n** - **delta**))th and (*v2* = (*k** * **s**)/(**n** + **delta**)
>   )th smallest elements in **S'**.  Almost certainly, the kth smallest
>   element in **S** will fall between **v1** and **v2**, so we are left with a
>   selection problem on (**2** * **delta**) elements. With low  probability, the
>   kth smallest element does not fall in this range, and we have
>   considerable work to do. However, with a good choice of **s** and **delta**,
>   we can ensure, by the laws of probability, that the second case does
>   not adversely affect the total work.

I do not follow the above text. Can anyone please explain to me with examples. How did the author reduce to **2** * **delta** elements? And how does he know that there is a low probablity that element does not fall into this category.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you link to the article, please?

Comment: -1 for still not linking to the article. We have no context for your fragment. It's something about comparing elements, it might be sorting, but there's no way to be sure without considerable knowledge of this particular subject, and maybe even then there's too little to go by.

Answer (score 0):

The basis for the idea is that the normal selection algorithm has linear runtime complexity, but in practical terms is slow. We need to sort all the elements in groups of five, and recursively do even more work. `O(n)` but with too large a constant. The idea then, is to reduce the number of comparisons in the selection algorithm (not a selection sort necessarily). Intuitively it is the same as in basic statistics; if I take a sample subspace of large enough proportion, it is likely that the distribution of data in the subspace adequately reflects the data in the whole space.

So if I'm looking for the kth number in a set of size one million, I could instead take say 10 000 (already one hundredth the size), which is still large enough to be a good representation of the global distribution, and look for the k/100th number. That's simple scaling. So if the space was 10 and I was looking for the 3rd, that's like looking for the 30th in 100, or the 300th in 1000, etc. Essentially `k/S = k'/S'` (where we're looking for the kth number in S, and we translate that to the k'th number in S' our subspace) and therefore `k' = k*S'/S` which should look familiar, since in the text you quoted S' is denoted by s, and S by n, and that's the same fraction quoted.

Now in order to take statistical fluctuations into account, we don't assume that the subspace will be a perfect representation of the data's distribution, so we allow for some fluctuation, namely, delta. We say let's find the k'th-delta and k'th+delta elements in S', and then we can say with great certainty (i.e. high mathematical probability) that the kth value from S is in the interval (k'th-delta, k'th+delta).

To wrap it all up we perform these two selections on S', then partition S accordingly, and now do [normal] selection on the much smaller interval in the partition. This ends up being almost optimal for the elements outside the interval, because we don't do selection on those, only partition them. So the selection process is faster, because we have reduced the problem size from S to S'.

Comment: Hi Davin, in last paragraph as you mentioned two selections means k'th-delta and k'th+delta, what do u mean by then partition S accordingly?

Comment: @venkysmarty, once you've made those two selections on S', you need to  partition S so that you have all elements smaller than `k'-delta`, all between `k'-delta` and `k'+delta'` and then the rest. Then, based on that partition you can find the kth element.

Comment: so basically we are again doing n comparision of all elements in S while partioning, so how we reduce comparisions above, thanks for answering my questions patiently, i am new to algorithms and tyring to understand it, and another question is that after partion we do selection in 2delta elements

Comment: @venkysmarty, partitioning is a single comparison, selection is more. So selection on S performs more than one comparison on all elements, while this version performs one comparison on most elements, and then more (selection) on only a small subset.